# A being cooked pie

Tags: passive-voice, present-continuous, active-vs-passive

I can say:

> I am throwing a pie which I am cooking.

Then I can say:

> I am throwing a pie which is being cooked by me

Then:

> I am throwing a pie which is being cooked

Can I say:

> I am throwing a being cooked pie

OR

> A being cooked pie is being thrown by me?

Comment: If you are cooking a pie, you can't be throwing it.....Also, we say making a pie. If the pie is being cooked, it's in the oven....

Comment: do you mean throw a pie when it has finished being cooked, custard pie style? or are you referring to pizza preparation spinning the dough around to shape it?

Comment: Oh, for cooking\making - thank you.
Okay, let's see this way.
I am not interested in the context and absurdity, only in the grammar part.
If we take two eggs, put them onto the frying pen, turn the gas on and make the eggs. The eggs are being made by the fire\frying pan\our neighbour etc.
Then she(who isn't making the eggs) and takes the frying pan with the eggs and throw away. Then is gets to be "being made eggs are being thrown away by her". It may be funny or dumb but what about the grammar? Can the "being done something" form exist?

Answer (score 1):

- He is playing a tune which he is humming.
- He is playing a tune which is being hummed by  him. [awkward but grammatical]
- He is playing a tune which is being hummed. [we don't know by whom]

Please note: being hummed is not an adjective that can be pre-positioned to a noun.

So, to answer the question: "being hummed tune" is not grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, one can "throw a pizza".  A pizza is a kind of "pie".  But one "throws" the pizza when the dough is still raw, in order to spin it into shape.  One does not throw the pizza while it is cooking.

To my knowledge, pizzas are the only kind of pie that are "thrown" during their preparation.

Comment: Very funny, in fact.

Comment: Disregarding Dean Martin, is a pizza really a pie?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey -- I don't think I'll ever get [that song](https://www.bing.com/search?q=dean+martin+pizza+pie+that+s+amore) out of my head, so I can't disregard him.  But even so, a pizza does have important similarities to other kinds of pie:  It has a crust, it has a *de facto* filling (the tomato sauce and/or cheese), it can have toppings, and it is baked.  The usual shape is a shallow circular cylinder, with allowances for the how the bottom crust has to rise to reach the top surface. Meat pies and vegetable pies used to be common.

Comment: I never really thought about it until a certain episode of "The Sopranos", and ever since it has had a slightly sinister air. Personally I think that you may as well call a tortilla a "tortilla omelette". I note that some Americans call lasgagne 'lasagna noodles'.

Comment: I had a steak-and-ale pie for my lunch yesterday.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey At EL&U: *[Where does “pizza pie” originate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263732/)*

Comment: I was being rhetorical; I know how "pizza pie" originated.

Comment: No, I meant "throwing away" out of the window... :D

Answer (score -1):

You can say

> A pie being cooked is being thrown at me

though, as commenters have noted, the situations in which a pie can be getting cooked and getting thrown at the same time are rare.

*A being cooked pie…* would not be idiomatic. Your example construction is a [reduced relative clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/intermediate-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-relative-clauses), and *being cooked* functions here as a participle (a verb form used as an adjective). Participles are commonly placed after the word they modify, and passive participles almost exclusively so: *the play being reviewed could clinch the title*, essentially never *the being reviewed play could clinch the title*.

---

*[Cook](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cook_1)* and many similar verbs of food preparation like *toast*, *fry*, *bake*, or even *microwave* are flexible: a chef (or other preparer) can cook food, and the food can be cooked by the chef, but the food itself can also cook, intransitively.

> 1. I am roasting in the oven.
> 2. I am roasting a turkey in the oven.
> 3. A turkey is being roasted in the oven [by me].
> 4. A turkey is roasting in the oven.

This is mainly the case with preparation that involves cooking time without active intervention from the chef. *Chicken baking in a pan* is easier to envision than *chicken fricasseeing in a pan*, or *greens marinating in oyster sauce* as opposed to *greens stir-frying in oyster sauce*, although all would be permissible in the right context.

To the extent that such a thing is possible in real life, I would word your example as

> I am throwing a cooking pie.

Comment: That's because I don't like saying: "I am throwing a cooking pie" because there's 1% that maybe I meant I was throwing a pie which was cooking something different itself. But my sentence sense is "I am throwing a being cooked pie".
So, you mean the "being done something" form doesn't exist at all and it's not correct due to the grammar.
The only way to say "I am throwing a being cooked pie" is "I am throwng a pie being cooked"? Just I don't want to use 'which" or "that" but then the previous sentence can mean that I am (throwing a pie) being cooked. That I am being cooked and throwing it...

Comment: Right. The *being done something* word order is generally not acceptable; the idiomatic form is *pie being cooked*. You can say *a pie being cooked is being thrown by me* as I note, but that would be awkward — it is uncommon to indicate personal agency with *by me* — hence my preference for *I am throwing*.

Comment: Okay, then how would I distinguish the sentence :I am talking to a person being killed.
1) I am being killed and at the same time I am talking to the person
2) I am talking to the person WHO is being killed
How to distinguish them or how to live further if there's no way of distinguishing?

Comment: *I am talking to a person being killed* will almost never be interpreted as *I am being killed while talking to a person*. At best, it would be set off with a pause when speaking or a comma in writing. Language is not logic. Sometimes the only way to make something unambiguous is to add explanatory phrases or sentences.

Comment: How would it be with the comma?

But you never use any commas... it's not russian.

But even with the intonation\pause it may be both. It depends on what you want to highlight...=(

Comment: *I am talking to a person, being killed* is somewhat more likely to be interpreted that you are being killed, rather than the other person, but this is again an extremely unnatural way of expressing the idea. I cannot tell at this point whether you are trying to express one idea or the other or to be deliberately ambiguous.

Comment: Okay, then how would you say it meaning "talking to the person while being killed" completely clearly for the person without any ambiguous variants?
Or it will be as I said "while being killed"?